# Heroku push rejected no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

i have this common heroku error `!     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected`
 tryting to push after the following executions:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -a -m "First commit"
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

I have seen many errors specific to `Ruby on Rails` projects, i just want to push a PHP project and for now i am just trying to push a simple `index.html` file

I also tried to do

```
git init
git add .
git commit -a -m "First commit"
heroku create --stack cedar
git push heroku master
```

But i get the same issue... What am i missing ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try renaming it to `index.php` that will detect it as a PHP application.